# Rendering shiny steel on a white background?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, lighting, hdri

Even though there are several other questions with answers in this blog, I found the answers to my following question very useful.

I want to render animations of a shiny type of steel, for example, the goal is having a rendering like this, but with a white background!

[image: Rendering a shining part in white background]

It seems the lighting, environment and HDRI are important, but I could not make it work!
The result of my rendering is this picture:
[image]

Can you please have a look at this file and give any hints about any changes that I should do?
[image]

Thanks,
Kind regards

Comment: Thanks @JachymMichal. you are right! I modified my main post. I appreciate it

Comment: Thanks @susu, I went through that post before, but I was not able to have a white background and keep having a shining surface! it seems it needs a HDRI, which I am not good at it, that is the reason I requested Jachym Michal to learn from his file

Comment: An HDRI is not a magical thing, you can totally do this without one with proper lighting, placing your own lights and playing with the size, direction and intensity will allow you total control.

Comment: Susu's right, the HDRI saves time, but isn't necessary. I only used it to make the process simpler :).

Comment: Thanks so much @JachymMichal. Honestly, it is quite some days that I am struggling with light, nodes, intensity and so on, but I was not successful! that was the reason I requested for help here :-). I will review the file and suggestion of Susus and you and will try to apply it to my model

Comment: Yeah, a good lighting setup is something I often strugle with, too :). Good luck with your project, and feel free to ask more questions here, that's always welcome.

Comment: The main problem with your setup is that you have way too many lights and no particular purpose for them, as they completely surround the object.
Light has two main purposes: allow you to see the objects shape, and reveal the characteristics of the material.

Comment: On top of that the world with nodes that have no logic. 
Delete all of the lights and world. Add a single area light and see what it does. Place it in different places and note how the shading reveals the object and how the reflections work. Only then add more lights and do the same. The Shapes for shiny objects are largely determined by the environment they reflect. Strategic placing of Lights and Dark objects will help you get to what you want.

Comment: Also note that scale does matter, Try to work in a scale that resembles the real world. By having a very large object (yours is 14x40 meters long) forces you to have not only very large lights, but having those lights be very bright.

Comment: Here's a rough modification to [the original file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8Qyal2aY/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are just three things you need to get such result:

1. A studio lighting HDRI ([like this one shipped with Blender](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=studio&h=studio_small_01))
2. Shiny metallic material (*Metalness=1, Roughness=0.2*)
3. Transparent background (*RenderTab > Film > Transparent*)

Rotate the HDRI to your needs, and add white background through compositor :).

[image]

Comment: Bravo! Thanks so much @JachymMichal !! Is it also possible to share your blender file please for my practice? yours looks fantastic!!

Comment: Hey :). No problem, [here it is on GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lYFbmvCUoKPr6ILlAhrivclp1Bb_87Uj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=8Qyal2aY" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8Qyal2aY/)

Comment: Dear @susu, I really thank you for working on my file! I learned a lot. With your help, I found out one of my biggest mistakes ever! I had a really wrong impression about the unit of power of lights there :-), I was comparing with physical W :-)))

Comment: Dear @JachymMichal, thanks for sharing your file and also your help :-)